# How do you copy properties of an object into another without adding properties using Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to copy the right object into the left object without copy properties that are in the right object into the left. In the end, I only want the properties that exist in the left object. I can use JavaScript and jQuery

```
var left = { "id": "123" };
var right = { "id": "456", "no": "false" };

$.each(left, function (l1_key, l1Value) {
  if (typeof l1Value === 'object') {
    const left_l2 = left[l1_key];
    const right_l1_properties = right[l1_key]; 
    $.each(left_l2, function (l2_key, l2Value) {
      l2Value = right_l1_properties[l2_key];
    });
  }
});
```

left need to be:

```
{ "id": "456" };
```

Comment: So you only want to copy the values from right to left, for the keys that are already in the left object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply iterate over all properties in the left object, check if that key exists in the right object, and set the left keyed value to the right keyed value.

```js
var left = { "id": "123" }; var right = { "id": "456", "no": "false" };

for (var prop in left){
  if(prop in right) {
    left[prop] = right[prop];
  }
};

console.log(left);
```

No jQuery needed.

EDIT: rather than using if(right[prop]), it does make more sense to be a little more object-happy and use either `hasOwnProperty` or `in` to check for the existence of the matching property in right. I've updated the code to use `in`. [A discussion on `in` vs `hasOwnProperty`.](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/the-uses-of-in-vs-hasownproperty.html)

Comment: You may want to do a "hasOwnProperty" check here too.

Comment: short and elegant. resharper suggested I add hasOwnProperty but I think that would be optional in my scenario. thanks.

Comment: I am realizing is that I need to go deeper into the properties. Need to copy the properties of each property AND only if the first level of properties exist and if the second level exists. I like how simple this is and am wondering if there is an easy way to go deeper. If not, does jQuery have something?

Comment: Are you referring to nested properties?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` on `left` and `Array.forEach` to iterate over the array of `left` properties. That way you could exclude properties from `right` that don't match. The complete logic is implemented in the snippet below.

```js
function changeMatchingProps(left, right) {
if (typeof left === 'object' && typeof right === 'object') {
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(left).forEach(function (val, idx, array) {
    if(right.hasOwnProperty(val)) {
          left[val] = right[val];
    }
});
}
}
var left = { "id": "123" };
var right = { "id": "456", "no": "false" };
changeMatchingProps(left, right);
console.log(left);
var left = { "id": "123", "no": "false", "yes": "true" };
var right = { "id": "456", "no": "true" };
changeMatchingProps(left, right);
console.log(left);
var left = { "id": "123", "pid": "" };
var right = { "id": "456", "no": "false", "pid": "afd39cb123df" };
changeMatchingProps(left, right);
console.log(left);
var left = { "id": "123" };
var right = {};
changeMatchingProps(left, right);
console.log(left);
```

Comment: This is great, but one thing I am realizing is that I need to go deeper into the properties. Need to copy the properties of each property AND only if the first level of properties exist and if the second level exists. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: @MattEdwardsCdn in case your objects have nested objects meaning `var left = { "name": {"first": "John", "last": "Doe"} };` then you need a recursive function that will produce the desired output. But i am not sure i understand the terms `first level of properties exist and if the second level exists`... Try to open a new question adding the object code in your example and a description of the desired functionality of this phrase `AND only if the first level of properties exist and if the second level exists`